# Cant Hide Notification bar in Android 4.3 API 18

Tags: android, android-notification-bar, android-titlebar, android-4.3-jelly-bean

Prior to 4.3,

```
@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar
```

and

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`
```

works perfectly to hide the Notification bar. But in 4.3 though the bar is not showing using this code but sliding at the top bring the bar

[image: Sliding shows the screen. See that the bar overlapped 134.]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out there is no simple way to do it. So I use bit of reflection and its working fine.

```
Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapsePanels");
collapse .setAccessible(true);
collapse .invoke(service);
```

Don't forget to add this in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
```

Comment: does this hide the bar only in the current activity?

Comment: I invoked it on touch listeners for every `Activity`.

Comment: Suppose you call another application from your activity, is there any way to hide notification bar in those called applications?

Comment: you can make a background service for that

Comment: OK, I dunno how but that's a good starting point, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen?

Comment: See images. The notification bar is hidden but gesture at the top of the screen bring it back.

Comment: You said you were using android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar, not        android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen.